# Can't play gif when using freeTTS Voices - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, voice

I am using freeTTS to speak out some text, in the background i want a animated gif to keep playing
When i try this: as soon as the voice starts speaking, the image in background gets hanged even if i keep it in some other JFrame... and after the speech is completed it starts moving. I want it to run properly without pauses.
I am placing a animated gif in a label by importing it to my application and changing the icon to that image in label' properties.

**Edit**
Here is my code:

```
 private void RandomjBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Voice voice;
        voice = voiceManager.getVoice(VOICENAME);
        voice.allocate();
        voice.speak("Daksh"); 
    }
```

I am actually using a lot of setVisible, setText, declaration of integers, calculating on them but i have removed them to simplify the code for you to understand. Still it gives the same problem if executed.

The button 'RandomjB' is clicked from another button by the following code:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(zad, new ActionListener() {
    int tick = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Success" + ++tick);
              RandomjB.doClick();
              final int col = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());;
      if (tick >= col) {
        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
      for(int g=0; g<col; g++){
    jButton2.setVisible(true); // Check Button -> Visible

}
      }

    }
  });



  timer.setInitialDelay(0);
  System.out.format("About to schedule task.%n");
   timer.start(); 
  System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do some research on [Threads and Concurrency](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/&ei=jltQUuetBfOa0AWT6oCAAw&usg=AFQjCNEUmZflePUsZWashn56WonFUU7h0A&sig2=XHvYnHVQpCc4LTyVSyCwEA&bvm=bv.53537100,d.Yms)

These allow two things to operate simultaneously, this is just my assumption.

Assuming that you instantiate some kind of class for the FreeTTS you may want to do something like this

```
FreeTTSClass tts;

new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        tts = new FreeTTSClass();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I went onto the link you suggested but that didn't help much as i was unable to get it properly and couldn't understand how to use that in my code

Comment: I didnt initiate any class for this, what i did was simple that i had put the code in a button, nothing else. I am 14 years old and new to java. i have no idea about what you answered. if u want i can upload my code of the button. Pls Help

Comment: It's nice to know that younger people are getting into programming, welcome to the community. Pasting your code will help.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without the code, I however assume that you loop the speech synthesis within the one and only Swing-Thread and therefore block all kind of window updates as long as the speech loop is in progress.

As stated by Shaun Wild: you need to use a second Thread for the speech loop.